# Class inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, class, project

I have one project IBSampleApp used in two solutions and it’s classes suffer the following compiler error in both.

> inaccessible due to it’s protection level

Error in IBClient.cs of IB Execution project in Execution solution:

[image]

TickPriceMessage class in IBSampleApp project:

[image]

Added InternalsVisibleTo property to AssemblyInfo.cs of IBSampleApp project (recommended by @JamesFaix):

[image]

The problem persistes still. How to make TickPriceMessage class available to both solutions?

Comment: Code in question, not as images please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845634/internalsvisibleto-does-not-work

Comment: From where `Project.Execution` assembly name comes from? I do not see it anywhere...

Comment: Johnny, I’ve changed InternalsVisibleTo property to Project.IB Execution. Did not help

Answer (score 5):

You have a public constructor on an internal class. With lack of any access modifier, c# defaults to [the most restricted for the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c) which is `internal` for a class like yours.

```
// this is an "internal" class
class TickPriceMessage
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare TickPriceMessage class as `public`, it is `internal` by default.

Comment: Isn't that what OP's `InternalsVisibleTo` is for?

Comment: @John I wouldn't recommend that approach, unless you want some very-constrained visibility scenario. The most usual way is to declare the class as public.

Comment: Failed to get InternalsVisibleTo property work. Turned all classes public which resolves compiler error problem